# Como resolver o java.lang.nullpointerexception em aplicação com sqlite?

Tags: java, sqlite

Estou tendo problema com essa exceção. Tenho visto alguns tutoriais aqui, mas nenhum deles pode resolver o meu problema. Inclusive as respostas de perguntas parecidas não puderam satisfazer a minha necessidade.

Estou fazendo uma aplicação desktop com java e SQLite.

Acho que o erro está aqui, pois ele só aparece na hora de logar, porém eu segui o tutorial a risca, mas na hora de apertar o enter aparece o erro:

> java.lang.nullpointerexception.

Segue o código para vocês analisarem:

```
   private void entrar() {

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM logins WHERE usuario = ? and senha = ?";

    try {

        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, nomeUser.getText());
        pst.setString(2, senhaUser.getText());

        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next()){
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login efetuado com sucesso");
        }else{
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login inexistente");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

    }

}
```

O erro completo seria

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at forms.login.entrar(login.java:156)
    at forms.login.btnEntrarKeyPressed(login.java:136)
    at forms.login.access$100(login.java:21)
    at forms.login$2.keyPressed(login.java:83)
    at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6493)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2832)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6312)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1954)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:806)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1074)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:945)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:771)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4762)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Tire esse try catch Exception, rode novamente e cole aqui o erro completo que vai sair no terminal, por favor.

Comment: Me parece que ou forms ou login está nulo. Pode colocar o resto do código?

Comment: o codigo é um pouco extenso, qual parte em particular você gostaria de ver?

Comment: Se mostrasse qual é a linha que deu erro, já ajudaria. Mas o erro ocorre por um problema fora deste método, então este trecho não vai ajudar.

Comment: Mostre a linha 156 de login.java

Comment: a linha 156 é esta   pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

Comment: Então conn está nulo, nesse momento.

Comment: Como eu faço para resolver Pablo, onde e como?

Comment: Em algum momento você deve inicializar sua variável conn. Ela faz referência a seu banco de dados, logo é necessário para realizar operações com o banco. Eg. conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db"); . [Aqui](https://www.matthewhollander.com/java-database-connectivity-mysql-oracle-and-sqlite/)  tem uma boa base para pesquisas.

Answer (score 1):

Olá!

Se é esta linha que está ocorrendo o problema :

```
pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
```

Então seu `Connection` está nulo!

Para que funcione, primeiramente temos que adicionar a biblioteca do SQLite em seu projeto.

[Segue o link para download!](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/sqlite/sqlite-jdbc-3.5.9.jar.zip)

Crie uma pasta chamada lib na raiz do projeto e adicione o jar.

Após clique com o botão direito no jar (dentro da pasta lib) e selecione a Opção

> Build Path

E em seguida

> Add to Build Path.

Isto irá adicionar ao projeto para que possa carregar seu `Connection`.

o próximo passo é criar um método que disponibilize a `Connection`

Segue um exemplo:

```
public static final Connection getConnection(){

try {

Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

return DriverManager.getConnection( (“jdbc:sqlite:nomeDoSeuBanco.db") );

} catch (final  Exception e) {

e.printStackTrace();

return null;

}
}
```

Ao utilizar a `Connection`, verifique se não está nula:

```
 private void entrar() {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM logins WHERE usuario = ? and senha = ?";
        try {
        Connection con = getConnection();

        if(null == con){
        // está nula, não consegui carregar, então ão poderemos continuar!
        return;

        }
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

            pst.setString(1, nomeUser.getText());

            pst.setString(2, senhaUser.getText());

            rs = pst.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next()){

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login efetuado com sucesso");
            }else{

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login inexistente");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

muito obrigado pela ajuda de todos, de fato o conn estava nulo, não devido a minha logica no metodo entrar(), mais devido não estar dando o retorno no metodo da conexão com o banco, eu estava fazendo a conexão de forma correta, porém não tinha retornado a conexão, ficou desta forma,

```
   public static Connection ConnectionDB(){

    try{
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/home/aminadabe/Documentos/DBmembresia/membresiaDB.sqlite");
       // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Deu certo");
       return conn;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }

    return null;
}
```

desta forma, resolvi o problema, obrigado a todos.